Counting a certain kind of permutations
In order to compute the expectation of certain random variables, I need to count the number of a kind of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ for every natural number $n$. Let it be $a_n$. For $n\le 3$ every permutation is a valid one, so $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$ and $a_3=6$. For $n\ge 4$, a permutation in the form of a list is valid if, starting from the fourth one, every term has at least one bigger and one smaller than it among the three preceding terms in the list.
For instance, for $n=6$ the permutation $(2,6,1,5,3,4)$ is valid, but $(2,6,1,3,4,5)$ is not, since $5>4$, $5>3$ and $5>1$.
I have written a small program to count the first values of $a_n$, and up to $n=13$ the sequence starts
$$
1,2,6,12,28,68,164,416,1088,2888,7888,22056,62712,\dots
$$
but I can'f find it in the OEIS or elsewhere.
It is very easy to note that if we change "three preceding terms" by "two preceding terms" (of course starting from the third one), then it would be $a_n=2$ for any $n\ge 2$. But the question seems to become drastically more complicated for three terms, and I didn't expect that.
I would appreciate any help with this.

fwiw, the data so far looks sort of exponential with a base slightly larger than $2.5$

These permutations can be viewed as avoiding a certain set of "consecutive permutation patterns" so you might look into the literature on that.  This question might be hard - I wouldn't necessarily expect it to have a closed form solution or generating function.  Probably you could at least prove that they grow at most exponentially.

Thank you so much, @Jair Taylor! Avoidance of (several) consecutive patterns seems definitively the topic here, and I guess it does exist an exponential bound for its growth from what I can show in other instances (the corresponding random variables have expectations such as $e^{H_n}$). The question seems to be hard, though I'm not sure to what extent the fact that the sequence does not appear at the OEIS is a proof... Besides, I posted the question in the hope that someone would find a recurrence, but I guess it would be the same as asking for a generating function.

Thank you as well, @Greg Martin!

I'd suggest adding it to OEIS yourself.  Then if you haven't made progress, check back every now and then to see if someone has :) Cheers
